# AJAX GET request not sending data to Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am trying to send data in `localStorage` via an AJAX GET request to Django, but the Django server never receives it. I am confident that I have data in `localStorage("preselection")` as `console.log` shows it. Here is my JavaScript snippet which is inside index.html (am a beginner, so apologies if this is basic and I'm avoiding jQuery for now):

```
var preselection = localStorage.getItem("preselection");

function previous_selection () {
  if (localStorage.getItem("preselection") != null) {
    console.log("PRESELECTION IS: ", preselection);
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("preselection", preselection);
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/');
    request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    request.send(data);

    request.onload = () => {
      var url = '/prebasket';
      window.location.href = url;

    };
    return false;
  }
}

previous_selection();
```

Below is my view in `views.py`. I tried `request.GET.dict()`, `request.GET.get()`, `request.GET.copy()`, etc. and my data comes as JSON in case it matters, but Django just gets an empty `{}` or `Null` for `q_preselection`:

```
@login_required
def index(request):
  q_preselection = request.GET.dict()
  print(q_preselection) # comes back empty
  context = { 
     #irrelevant 
             }
  return render(request, "pizza/index.html", context)
```

Comment: while I'm at it - I guess the ```csrf``` line isn't needed for this GET request..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) `send()` does not pass the body data for GET

> `send()` accepts an optional parameter which lets you specify the
>   request's body; this is primarily used for requests such as PUT. If
>   the request method is **GET** or HEAD, the body parameter is **ignored** and
>   the request body is set to null.

Use POST instead, you almost never want to have GET request with BODY ( parameters should be passed through URL for GET)

Comment: But I want to redirect the user straight to another page if localStorage isn't empty - in my understanding POST is often used when the user actively submits a form, or generally required user action? Thanks again